# To whom is the advaita guru parampara shloka attributed to?

Tags: advaita, shloka

To whom the following shloka is attributed to?

> sadasiva samarambham sankaracarya madhyamam
>    asmad acarya paryantam vande guru paramparam"

Who is the author of this shloka?